# How do i make static values as dynamic values

Tags: dynamic, static, dojo

In addSeries method there are values which are declared static i want to give it dynamically Please can anyone make it for me /...................This is dojo code

```
require(["dojox/charting/Chart", "dojox/charting/axis2d/Default", "dojox/charting/plot2d/StackedAreas", "dojox/charting/themes/Wetland" , "dojo/ready"],
              function(Chart, Default, StackedAreas, Wetland, ready){
                ready(function(){
                  var c = new Chart("chartOne");
                  c.addPlot("default", {type: StackedAreas, tension:3})
                    .addAxis("x", {fixLower: "major", fixUpper: "major"})
                    .addAxis("y", {vertical: true, fixLower: "major", fixUpper: "major", min: 0})
                    .setTheme(Wetland)
                    .addSeries("Series B", [1, 2, 0.5, 1.5, 1, 2.8, 0.4])
                    .addSeries("Series C", [2.6, 1.8, 2, 1, 1.4, 0.7, 2])
                    .addSeries("Series D", [6.3, 1.8, 3, 0.5, 4.4, 2.7, 2])

                .render();
            });
        });
```

Comment: Where do you get your Data from? An Array, a Store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change it like this:

```
var arraySer1 = [1, 2, 0.5, 1.5, 1, 2.8, 0.4];
var arraySer2 = [2.6, 1.8, 2, 1, 1.4, 0.7, 2];
var arraySer3 = [6.3, 1.8, 3, 0.5, 4.4, 2.7, 2];

 require(["dojox/charting/Chart", "dojox/charting/axis2d/Default", "dojox/charting/plot2d/StackedAreas", "dojox/charting/themes/Wetland" , "dojo/ready"],
          function(Chart, Default, StackedAreas, Wetland, ready){
            ready(function(){
              var c = new Chart("chartOne");
              c.addPlot("default", {type: StackedAreas, tension:3})
                .addAxis("x", {fixLower: "major", fixUpper: "major"})
                .addAxis("y", {vertical: true, fixLower: "major", fixUpper: "major", min: 0})
                .setTheme(Wetland)
                .addSeries("Series B", arraySer1)
                .addSeries("Series C", arraySer2)
                .addSeries("Series D", arraySer3)

            .render();
        });
    });
```

Here's the fiddle for that : http://jsfiddle.net/WdDxM/

First you define the Arrays you need, then fill in the Data.
The array can be filled with the Data from a Store or whereever you get your Data from.

Regards